# Is it possible to permanently disable CSS on Android browsers?

Tags: browser, browser-add-ons

Is it possible to permanently disable CSS on Android browsers like Firefox, Dolphin, Chrome and Opera?

I want the browsers to completely ignore **any** stylesheet rule.

Can this be achieved with the help of AdBlock Plus?

Comment: Adblock Plus might indeed be the right thing for this. You could setup a rule to discard all URLs ending with `.*\.css$` (for external style sheets) at least. Not sure however if you can block internal css. Maybe those declared via the `<style>` rule, but most likely not the direct ones (`style="..."`). Here you might check for GreaseMonkey or the like, if it's available for the browsers and JavaScript is not an issue.

Comment: Definitely possible to do this on my Desktop Chrome's ABP by adding a custom filter of `*.css` - However I was unable to find a place within the Android app to add a custom filter.

Comment: I sense that you're having an XY problem. May I ask Y? CSS poses little to no security risk, and most pages without CSS screams ugly.

Comment: No. I am not having an XY problem. I need to disable CSS in order to eliminate ad overlays on online sport streaming sites. They can look ugly, I don't care. However, embedded Flash player will still work with its "full screen" button.

Comment: You're pretty much asking the same thing as the ability to disable HTML. Not really possible. The most you may be able to do is disable Javscript. There must be a brighter solution to your problem.

Comment: I should've stated that I am looking to disable loading of external CSS files.

Comment: @Temuri: if you want to block ads, that's your Y, see the Adblock Plus solution suggested by Izzy and Dylan Yaga. Adblock Plus can disable just the anything ads while keeping the page layout intact.

Answer (score 1):

I have to suggestions that are probably going to be about as close as you're going to get to removing the 'styles' from websites. They're there for a reason, like previously mentioned, and removing them is *very close* to disabling the HTML but not entirely the same as you're stil left with the paragraphs and links (the core content of the site, just without the look and formatting).

The first suggestion will replace (not remove) a lot of the CSS from the pages. The add-on is called Stylish, just do a search for it in Firefox Mobile, and then go to 'Menu' -> 'Tools' -> 'Add-Ons', tap the Stylish add-on, and then the 'manage styles' button. When the page opens there's a link that you can click on that will direct you to a page that has a ton of '*styles*', which will let you change the whole look of either one, several, or all web pages.

The second suggestion is to use an app like [Pocket](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ideashower.readitlater.pro&hl=en) (which is what I currently use and *love*) that will let you easily save a page from nearly any browser (using an add-on) into your 'Pocket' and then view it as an article (with the CSS/styles completely removed from the content). Another major benifit of Pocket is you can configure the settings in the app to store all of the pages offline so you can access them even without an internet connection (extremely useful for tablets that don't have mobile data).

I know these suggestions aren't *exactly* what you were looking for but I'm hoping that between the two you'll be able to accomplish what you are trying to. I did search the web for a few minutes and didn't find a way to completely disable the style sheets in any mobile browser or I would have posted my findings.

Note: You can completely disable the styles on a PC (and probably a Mac) by using the [Web Developer plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/), there's a Chrome version as well but I can't provide the link because I don't have the 'reputation' on stackexchange yet. After you install the plugin, you can quickly disable them using the shortcut key combo `Alt + Shft + A` or by clicking the CSS menu button and navigating to `CSS > Disable Styles > Disable All Styles`. Hope this helps!